# Quantify Protein Denaturation with Change in Solubility

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, protein-folding, alcohol

I plan to run a lab which compares the impacts of ethanol and methanol, in varying concentrations, on the denaturation of whey protein.

Change in water solubility is a good indicator of the degree of denaturation in a protein, but online research doesn't seem to be showing any exceedingly simple method of quantifying a change in solubility. Can protein precipitation be used to measure solubility? If so, I have access to a centrifuge, ammonium sulfate and just about any other chemical compound. Are there any better methods, altogether?

Is change in solubility the only factor which may reflect denaturation?
Thank you

Comment: How do you plan to actually measure the protein?

Comment: By mass scale. I need a way to find the solubility of the protein solution, as in solution of saturation.

Comment: How pure is your sample?

Comment: I’m varying the samples by solution of ethanol or methanol (Ex 1:1 ethanol/water ratio).

Comment: Mass of protein is kept as a constant, as well as volume of solution

Comment: To answer your question though, the whey protein I’m using is 95% pure.

Comment: There are many ways to assess protein denaturation. Keep in mind that denaturation and precipitation are not necessarily coupled. For instance, detergents can denature proteins and yet make them quite soluble. It seems that you are asking two separate questions here. If you decide that protein solubility is what you want to measure, we can suggest some simple protocols.

Comment: I have decided to simply separate the formed precipitate from the solution with a centrifuge, filter the precipitate with filter paper, determine the mass of the precipitate, and find a ratio between that mass and the full mass of the utilized protein sample. Is that a good way to assess the degree to which the protein was denatured? It seems to me like my best option...